# qemu-i386: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux.so.2': No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I'm trying to install anaconda 32bit in Linux but I getting this type of error.

**ERROR:**

Cannot execute native linux-32 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux f4b53cf6c2f4 5.10.104-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 17 17:05:54 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You don't have the appropriate 32bit libraries installed. Check which library has /lib/ld-linux.so.2 file and install it (probably glibc, afai remember). But this is definitely not SO question.